# Method mysteriously exits execution in the middle to resume the rest of the program?

Tags: ios, objective-c

So i've got this code that tries to find an unused upload name, using the user's email and a number at its end. It does this with a list of uploaded objects we've already collected, the user's email.(upload_name), and the 
current number that might be open (it is incremented when a match is found).

The list is not sorted, and it's pretty tricky to sort for a few reasons, so I'm having the method read through the list again if it reaches the end and the upload_number has changed.

```
- (NSString*)findUnusedUploadNameWithPreviousUploads:(NSMutableArray*)objects withBaseUploadName:(NSString*)upload_name {
        previous_upload_number = upload_number;

        for (NSString *key in objects) {
            // the component of the object name before the first / is the upload name.
            NSLog([key componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"][1]);
            if ([[key componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"][1]
                 isEqualToString:([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%ld", S3KeyUploadName1, upload_number])]) {
                upload_number++;
                NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"upload name: %@_%ld", S3KeyUploadName1, upload_number]);
            }
            NSLog(@"pang");
        }

        NSLog(@"ping");
        if (previous_upload_number == upload_number) {
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%ld", upload_name, upload_number];
        }

        return [self findUnusedUploadNameWithPreviousUploads:objects withBaseUploadName:upload_name];
}
```

The problem is, the program never reads the "ping". it just leaves the method after the first for loop is done.

Edit: No the NSlogs are fine, you can do simple string OR StringWithFormat.

Edit: Don't mind the unnecessary use of recursion, I did this because the simple way was having the same problem and i wanted to see if a different (albeit unnecessarily recursive)  way would share that problem. It does.

Edit: I set a breakpoint in the for loop, and I set a break point at the "ping". It does not reach the ping. It completes the for loop and the ditches the whole thing.

Edit: Please try to help me figure out why it's exiting the the method immediately after the for loop. I'm aware this is stylistically meh, and I promise I'll make it shiny and spotless when it works. =]

Edit: to be clear, the method DOES exit. it does so *early* I know this because the rest of the program following this method (which is not threaded such that it wouldn't have to wait for it) runs AFTER this for loop, consistently.

Comment: First you need to fix the first two `NSLog` statements. `NSLog` is must like `stringWithFormat`. It needs to be `NSLog(@"some string with optional format specifiers", arg1, arg2, ..., argN);`.

Comment: BTW - this looks like an inappropriate use of recursion. Why use recursion for this when it appears a simple loop will do?

Comment: There is also the inconsistent use of `upload_name` and the formatting of the string.  Also `previous_upload_number` is an instance variable for some reason.  In short, this is never going to work.

Comment: If you add a breakpoint and run it step by step you should see whats happening

Comment: @trojanfoe not sure what you mean. the previous upload_number just gets set over and over again and only needs context for the current context. Whether they overlap doesn't matter because it keeps getting changed. I just didn't want to allocate for like 35 "previous_upload_number"s.

Comment: "the method DOES exit" Please explain how you made sure this is the case.

Comment: Quick check: Make sure every `key` in `objects` actually is an `NSString`, before hitting the conditional in the loop. Even better: Set and activate an exception breakpoint in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possible explanations for the described behavior:

- The method **never exits**. For some reason it blocks or performs infinitely somewhere in the loop. Make sure this is not the case by setting a breakpoint after the place where the message is called (i.e. the place to where it should return).
- The method, or some method it calls, **throws an exception**. While seldom and unsupported in productive Cocoa code it could be some misbehaving 3rd party library or just a simple programmer error, where Cocoa actually does throw. Make sure this does not happen by setting an exception breakpoint in Xcode.
- **Undefined behavior**. This is, sadly, part of official C and heavily exploited by modern compilers. It basically means: Anything can happen, if there's something in your code, where the standard says that the behavior is not defined. One example would be accessing a deallocated object. Another fine reason of undefined behavior can be threads accessing common data in an unsynchronized way.

Other than exceptions there's no explanation for a method to "exit early". If you still can't find the reason I suggest you invest some time to learn the debugger. Single stepping, like Aris suggested, might be a way to find out what's going on.

Comment: it DOES exit. it does so early, and that's the problem. 

No exceptions appear to be thrown, nor should they. All of the things used here are basic Objective C classes.